# Parallel.ForEach loop Allow only one thread to access DB in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a piece of code where multiple threads are accessing using a shared ID property from ConcurrentBag type of string like following:

```
var ids = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
// List contains lets say 10 ID's 
var apiKey = ctx.ApiKey.FirstOrDefault();

Parallel.ForEach(ids, id => 
{
    try
    {
        // Perform API calls
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "Expired")
        {
            // the idea is that if that only one thread can access the DB record to update it, not multiple ones
            using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                var findApi= ctx.ApiKeys.Find(apiKey.RecordId);
                findApi.Expired = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
                findApi.FailedCalls += 1;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

So in a situation like this if I have a list of 10 ids and 1 key that is being used for API call, once the key reachces hourly limit of calls, I will catch the exception from the API and then flag the key not to be used for the next hour.

However, in the code I have pasted above, all of the 10 threads will access the record from DB and count the failed calls as 10 times, instead of only 1..:/

So my question here is how do I prevent all of the threads from doing the update of the DB record, but instead to only allow one thread to access the DB, update the record (add failed calls by +1) ?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Never use exception handling for controlling program flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/2719).

Comment: @UweKeim  could you elaborate a little bit more on that topic ? ^_^ Maybe in a form of answer so I can read further :D

Comment: Why not click the link I commented?

Comment: @UweKeim ah okay got it, didn't see the link earlier... And related to the question, is there any way I can allow just 1 thread to access the DB record instead of all 10 at once ? :D

Comment: [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)?

Comment: @vasily.sib so basically I would lock the DB object , and then update it if I got it correctly ? I just wonder how it would look like in my case

Comment: What are you doing in the Parallel.ForEach()? If you are only accessing the DB and you only want one Thread to do that then there is no reason to Parallel as a normal foreach will do it just as fast.

Comment: no, not DB object. Use some shared resource. Docs have a sample code.

Comment: @vasily.sib lock(findApi) { // Then update it ?  } is this it ?

Comment: `lock(findApiLockObject) { if (!done) { /* update it */ done = true; } }`

Comment: @MindSwipe I added a note earlier that the parallel foreach is doing api calls (which is network limited) so the calls are being made faster with parallel instead of the regular foreach loop :D

Comment: You also need to handle the fact that 2 different threads might end up in the exception handler because of this. Even if you lock, you will still need to detect that one thread has already stored this lockout and the other thread doesn't need to.

Comment: How about using parallel code to do the initial code, then gather all those that were expired in a separate list, do a distinct on that, and run a separate loop afterwards to lock out the id's?

Comment: Basically, take parallelism out of the loop that flags them as locked out, and handle the multiple id's problem before it?

Comment: @vasily.sib i think your solution is closest to what I'm looking for , could you just put an answer so I can accept it ^_^ ?

Comment: Guys is @vasily.sib code right one? It seems like best solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a parallel loop, therefore the most likely behaviour is that each of the 10 threads are going to fire, try to connect to your API with the expired key and then all fail, throwing the exception.

There are a couple of reasonable solutions to this:

### Check the key before you use it

Can take the first run through the loop out of sequence? for example:

```
var ids = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
var apiKey = ctx.ApiKey.FirstOrDefault();

bool expired = true;

try {
  // Perform API calls
  expired = false;
}
catch(Exception ex) {
   // log to database once
}

// Or grab another, newer key?
if (!expired)
{
  Parallel.ForEach(ids.Skip(1), id => 
  {
     // Perform API Calls
  }
}
```

This would work reasonable well if the key was likely to have expired before you use it, but will be active while you use it.

### Hold on to the failures

If the key is possibly valid when you start but could expire while you are using it you might want to try capturing that failure and then logging at the end.

```
var ids = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
var apiKey = ctx.ApiKey.FirstOrDefault();

// Assume the key hasn't expired - don't set to false within the loops 
bool expired = false;

Parallel.ForEach(ids.Skip(1), id => 
{
  try {
     // Perform API calls
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    if (e.Message == "Expired") {
      // Doesn't matter if many threads set this to true.
      expired = true;
    }
  }

  if (expired) {
    // Log to database once.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you only need to update apiKey.RecordId once if an error occurred, why not just track the fact that an error occurred and update once at the end?  e.g.

```
var ids = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
// List contains lets say 10 ID's 
var apiKey = ctx.ApiKey.FirstOrDefault();
var expired = false;

Parallel.ForEach(ids, id => 
{
    try
    {
        // Perform API calls
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "Expired")
        {
           expired = true;
        }
    }
}

if (expired)
{
   // the idea is that if that only one thread can access the DB record to 
   // update it, not multiple ones
   using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
   {
     var findApi= ctx.ApiKeys.Find(apiKey.RecordId);
     findApi.Expired = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
     findApi.FailedCalls += 1;
    }
});
```